# Creating realtime project with Hapi, MongoDb, NodeJS & AngularJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, real-time, rethinkdb, hapi.js

I'm creating my first web application using Hapi, MongoDb, NodeJS & Angular. I can already get and save some data from my app.

Now each time I need to refresh the data in the browser, I must restart the server. Because data is only fetched on server start, using the following function:

```
var getUsers = function(db, callback) {
    db.collection("users", function(err, collection) {

        if (err) return callback(err, "error getting collection");
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, users) {

            if (err) return callback(err, "error getting find()");

            console.log("returning users list: ");
            Common.setUsers(users);
            //console.log(Common.getUsers());
        });
    });
};
```

The users can then be fetched via `Common.getUsers()`

Now what if I want to create a list that shows me - in realtime - which users register for my application? So without a need for server restart. How can I achieve this?

I've done a bit of searching and found RethinkDb, which has [changefeeds](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/javascript/). (I wish I found this earlier). MongoDb doesn't have changefeeds the way Rethink implements it.

Is there a way that I can create these changefeeds myself? Or is there another tool that can achieve this for me which works with MongoDb?

Comment: You should put the getUsers function within a handler so you can call function when you receive a 'GET' request and return the array of users within collection.

Comment: Hey @Forza can you please just list out the whole process that you want to implement, I can help I believe. What you want is a little tough for me to grasp.

Comment: Hey @GandalftheWhite, what I'd like to achieve is that whenever something happens on the server, this becomes available automatically on the client. So for example whenever one user does a particular action like creating a todo item, then other users need to be able to see that when they log in. And without requiring me to restart the server every time :) Thx for helping me!

Comment: It seems simple and straightforward to me. Let's say there is a public timeline which 5 users have access to. Now on angular part I make a get request /gettimeline whenever a user is authenticated after user name and password entry -> I will route the request on the node js server end which will send Response JSON or whatever to Angular and then angular will show that data to user. It seems straightforward, if 5 users are logged in and some changes happen in the middle we can use a push notification to tell them that new data has been added to timeline, like stackoverflow and facebook notifies

Comment: please let me know if my answer is ambiguous by any means

Comment: Sounds good.. so basically you're saying what @simon-p-r said, create a route with a request to /gettimeline and then I can fetch the data realtime? But that means creating a route for many many functions. Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: Actually, the changefeed function from RethinkDb only returns changes made to the db. If i create the route like /gettimeline then it will always return all users. What if there are 10.000 users? I need it to only return the changes. Is that possible?

Comment: You could consider a WebSocket based cloud messaging platform like [Realtime Messaging](http://framework.realtime.co/messaging) (the company I work for). The AngularJS client would subscribe to a specific pub/sub channel where the node.js server would publish the user updates.

Comment: Hi Joao, I've looked at your service, but don't fully understand how it works. I cannot find one single video or tutorial on building a nodejs client-server application, which displays messages from the server in the client browser. Do you perhaps have an example on how to build a small app from scratch to finish? like [this one](http://knowthen.com/episode-10-building-realtime-applications-just-got-easy/) for rethink db.

Answer (score 2):

A little late but I created a playground application which shows how to build a realtime timeline with hapi and the nes plugin. It also utilizes RethinkDB and makes use of their changefeed feature: 
[Realtime timeline with hapi.js, nes and RethinkDB](http://mph-web.de/realtime-timeline-with-hapi-js-nes-and-rethinkdb/)

Maybe this also helps you a little bit.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I see this only now.. You have a very interesting sample application. Thanks for writing it! Do you think this concept is possible without RethinkDB changefeed? I have already created my application too much around MongoDB to switch now.

Comment: Glad to hear you like it. In the sample application I noted it would also work without RethinkDB changefeeds - you could just emit the newly created entry in the save method. So maybe in your case save the new item to MongoDB and emit it after that to the socket.